# Cognos 10.2.1 Active Reports Internet Explorer 11 incompatibility

Tags: internet-explorer, cognos, cognos-10

I'm experiencing an indentation problem with an active report in Cognos BI 10.2.1 version using Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.16663 since we updated our environment from Cognos 10.2.0. When I use a image component inside a data component (like list for example) the horizontal alignment is being shown as it was Left, but its set as Center. It seems to happen in other components as well and everything is centralized (yes, horizontal alignment has been tested). It seems to be a browser incompatibility because in Chrome the same problem is not happening. Any advice?

Comment: If you have a reproducible setup of this and you're running IE in compatibility mode, I'd suggest logging a call with support as this sounds like a bug in the 10.2.1 rendering.